# javascript prevent default for keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'p[contenteditable="true"]', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).after('<p contenteditable = "true"></p>');
        $(this).next('p').focus();
    } else if((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).text() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Should remove element.");
        $(this).remove();
        $(this).previous('p').focus();
    };
});
```

I would like to prevent the default action when a key is pressed. `preventDefault` works for `keypress` but not `keyup`. Is there a way to prevent the defualt for `$(document).on('keyup')`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No. `keyup` fires after the default action.

`keydown` and `keypress` are where you can prevent the default.
If those aren't stopped, then the default happens and `keyup` is fired.

Comment: Any one knows a reference to back this up?

Comment: @tutuDajuju It's pretty clear imo, even without a reference. If you hook into keyup then you can't "intercept" the actual key press anymore, since it has already been processed by keydown.

Comment: Is there any distinction between saying "`keyup` fires after the default action" and just saying "`keyup`'s default action cannot be prevented" ? Does the specification specifically dictate which order these actions happen in, or does it simply say that one action isn't affected by the other regardless of which happens first? Does it not technically matter either way?

Comment: @OOPSStudio If you tap a key (that being to press and release said key), the sequence is "key down", "keypress", "keyup". "keypress" is deprecated, but the order was specified in the W3C UIEvents spec (still listed in legacy section 9.3.2). There is a distinction to be made. First, it is expected that each event has a default action. The default I was referring to was the particular one that the poster was asking about (cancelable during keydown or keypress, not keyup; "beforeinput" would be correct today). But there is no default action for keyup; it's a notification that the action happened.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I assumed "the default action" in your answer was referring to `keyup`'s default action - but you were referring to the default action of the other events. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @OOPSStudio yeah, so what often happens is people want to know how to handle keystrokes, without allowing input to happen, and they are hoping that they can cancel the action on the keyup and get confused when it doesn't work. It's a completely different event that they should have cancelled, and the one they are trying to cancel is inert, because they update already happened. Fun story: I was having that conversation in 2018 with somebody, they didn't 100% trust me and came to SO, to get the answer... and found me, 5 years earlier.

Answer (score 8):

We can prevent the action by using following code snippet.

```
e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();  
      e.returnValue = false;
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      return false;
```

keyup fires after keydown/keypress. we can prevent default action in anyone of those events.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: It is not the proper answer for the asked question otherwise I would upvote it; however I really appreciate your efforts for providing this useful information.

Comment: dont use `keyup` , but use `keydown` and add his answer