# Why can I preventDefault event on keydown but not on keyup with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using `.keydown` I can capture keydown event, then check and prevent default action (display the character).

When using `.keyup` I cannot?

I know the event is being captured as `alert()` fires when the code is inside the condition yet the `preventDefault()` doesn't prevent the action.

Here is a full [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zbsWL/)

Comment: `keyup`'s action isn't to add a character to a field. That's already been and gone.

Comment: Should be obvious, when the keyup event fires, the key is released and the input is already there `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052592/javascript-prevent-default-for-keyup

Comment: You may want to trap `keypress`

Comment: Just tell yourself what happen when you keep a key dow? It does thisssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.

Comment: I did not see that in the 'similar questions' when creating this question

Comment: @Aaron I just googled for "prevent default for key up" and that was the first result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `keyup` event the character has been typed and can't be undone but in `keydown` nothing has been typed and the browser has *intent* to type the character, so you can cancel the browser intent.

Whenever you type a character the following events occur:

`keydown`  --> `keypress` repeatedly until the key is released  --> `keyup`

- `keydown` -> can be prevented -> fired when **press** a key
- `keypress` -> can be prevented -> fired when **hold** a key
- `keyup` -> cannot be prevented -> fired when **release** a key

Comment: What about `input` ?

Answer (score 0):

the `keydown()` event is fired when the key is hit, meaning that code can be executed before the key is released.

When the key is pressed code can prevent an action, because it simply hasn't happened yet, whereas on the `keyup()` event, it already has.

e.g. a character has already been inserted into an input field when triggering `keyup()`

in general, keydown and keyup produce the same keycodes (when used with a given event)
however keypress gives you the physical key pressed (ASCII code returned rather than keyCode)