# How to make escape key change url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { ... } 
});
```

The previous code is a code I found that determines if the <kbd>escape</kbd> key is pressed and released; however, I've never used code like this before.

1. I was wanting to find out if this was an okay code to use as far as security and performance?
2. I wanted to find out how to make this change the page url?  Basically, when they press the esc key and let go, it changes to the login page.
3. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: it isn't.  They aren't doing the same thing with it.  So they aren't changing the url.  Also, that doesn't really answer my questions about security and performance or whether there is a better way.  I've spent the last hour looking around online for this question.

Comment: You're probably looking for document.location. [example](http://jsbin.com/iPadONac/1)

Comment: 1. What are your security concerns? It's a simple key press. 2. There are plenty of samples for changing a page (as Kippie has linked). 3. Probably not (or atleast not worth worrying about), your requirement is fairly basic and this method should do fine

Comment: Kippie.  Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept your answer.  That did the trick.

Comment: Thank you musefan for answering the rest of my questions.  I just wanted to verify to make sure.  I've never used a feature like this before, so I like to make sure that I am doing things the correct way before implementing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the current url when pressing the esc button like so:

```
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var event = e.which || e.keyCode || 0; // .which with fallback

    if (event == 27) { // ESC Key
        window.location.href = 'YOURURL'; // Navigate to URL
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use jQuery's `$(window).keyup()` the same way.

Here we add an event listener to `onkeyup` to check for user interaction with the keyboard. When the user presses down and then releases a key the event will fire.

We then check if the key is the ESC key (`27`). Key code 27 (when using `.which`) is supported by the most popular browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, IE).

On a final note. To prevent any default action you can `return false;` on `keydown` or `keypress`; as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19689615/820519).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27) { window.location.href = 'http://example.com'; }
});
```